# Power BI Access to users outside the organization

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have created a Power BI dashboard with a Power BI Pro License.
Users in my organization can see the dashboard. However, users outside the organization cannot see the dashboard; they get a pop-up message asking them to do an upgrade.

I have seen articles that say that people with a free license can see the dashboard. Unfortunately, I have not been able to figure this out.

Is there a way for people without a Power BI license to visualize my dashboard? That is all I need.

Thank you!

Comment: There are 3 ways to do that - [Distribute Power BI content to external guest users with Azure AD B2B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-azure-ad-b2b), [Tutorial: Embed a Power BI report in an application for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-customer-app) or [Publish to web from Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use embed for your customers (also known as an app owns data) solution. In this approach, user will not need to sign in to Power BI.

The prerequisite for app owns data are:

- Azure Active Directory tenant.
- Service principal - An Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)/ Power BI Pro license/  A Power BI Premium Per User (PPU) license
- Code dependencies

2. You can also use "Publish to Web"

**Steps:**

- Open the report and select **File > Embed report > Publish to web (public).**
- Then copy the link to send it in email, or copy the HTML to paste into a website. You can embed it in code such as an iFrame, or paste it directly into a web page or blog.

**References:**

- [Embed content in your Power BI embedded analytics application - Power BI | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers)
- [GitHub - microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples: A collection of Power BI samples for developer use](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/)
- [Publish to web from Power BI - Power BI | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web)